# How can I add inline css using jquery data attribute with css3 prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This Code is good Working for background size inline css ex:

`style="background-size:cover"`

```
$(".tp-sliderSection .item").css('background-size', function(){
  $(this).css('background-size',$(this).data("bg-size"));
});
```

`<div data-bg-size="cover"></div>`

But I need to use it

```
$(".tp-sliderSection .item").css('background-size', function(){
  $(this).css('background-size',$(this).data("bg-size"));
  $(this).css('-webkit-background-size',$(this).data("bg-size"));
  $(this).css('-moz-background-size',$(this).data("bg-size"));
});
```

Output css style I need

```
  style="background-size:cover; -webkit-background-size:cover; -moz-background-size:cover"
```

ETC

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.8, the .css() setter will automatically take care of prefixing the property name.` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Your original code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code should have been working fine, but in case it didn't, you can try `.attr()`. I had often seen that sometimes there's a problem with `.data()` but `.attr()` seems to be the fix.

Also read: http://api.jquery.com/css/:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .css() setter will automatically take care of prefixing the property name. For example, take .css( "user-select", "none" ) in Chrome/Safari will set it as -webkit-user-select, Firefox will use -moz-user-select, and IE10 will use -ms-user-select.

Also one thing that is going wrong is returning. You just need to return the bg-size whereas you are setting it there. You had already made the function of `background-size` and now you just need to return the color. Have a look here: http://jsbin.com/xurevijunu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

> As of jQuery 1.4, .css() allows us to pass a function as the property value:
>
> $( "div.example" ).css( "width", function( index ) {
>         return index * 50;
>       });
>
> This example sets the widths of the matched elements to incrementally
>   larger values.
>
> **Note**: If nothing is returned in the setter `function (ie. function(
>   index, style ){} )`, or if `undefined` is returned, the current value is
>   not changed. This is useful for selectively setting values only when
>   certain criteria are met.

So, you can try:

```
$(".tp-sliderSection .item").css('background-size', function(){
  return $(this).attr("data-bg-size");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You can bracket the css with this syntax...

```
$(".tp-sliderSection .item").css('background-size', function(){
  $(this).css({ 'background-size’ : $(this).data('bg-size’),‘-webkit-background-size' : $(this).data('bg-size’), '-moz-background-size’ : $(this).data('bg-size')  });
 });
```

Comment: Hi "Marley" Thanks for your answer. How can it working? don't show -webkit-background-size -moz- in  inspect element only show background-siz so how it work's??

Comment: Try installing the mozilla add on “firebug” and inspect it with that. I would say that you probably aren’t seeing the “-webkit...” version because firefox is not a webkit browser and therefore doesn’t understand it. If you don’t see -moz in there either then that is because the browser will be translating it to simply “background-size” because it IS moz and therefore doesn’t need to show you the -moz bit. Use your script in all browsers and inspect in all browsers, then when modified do the same again and note down the differences.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to be clear. A browser will not show you its css prefixes usually. Like if you wrote -moz-someproperty then mozilla will strip out the -moz from it. If there was a browser called “dave” and you wrote -dave-background-color, then the browser “dave” would show “background-color” as the property.

Comment: And to add further clarification... The reason these vendor prefixes are used is to make changes in different browsers. If what you are trying to display and then change in jquery already shows up the same in all browsers with NO differences then all you need is simply “background-size”.

Comment: Yes it's working thank you so much for your answer I am really proud of you. Thanks..